Objectbox flutter: watch limit
My question will seem quite simple but i have hard time to find anything about limit watch in objectbox.
box.query().watch(triggerImmediately: true).map((e) => e.find());
I was able to do it like this. But stream()is not working as watch()
    final query = box.query().build();
    query.limit = 10;
    query.stream();


I want to watch the data which is added to the box and emit it. So for e.g if i add 20 items and i want to use limit 10. Then it should emit 10 last items added and not all 20.

If I understood your question correctly, you need to limit stream's output which you gather from ObjectBox.
If so, you can use something like this:
box.query().watch(triggerImmediately: true).map((e) => e.find()).take(10);

Explanation: First, you create QueryBuilder object with query. Then, when you start watching it with watch, you "convert" your query to Stream object. map transforms every new value from this stream with transformer function ((e) => e.find() in your case).
In the end, you have Stream. And if you want to limit quantity of results from this stream, you use take. And that's how your stream will produce at most 10 values (can be less, depends in what query returns)

watch() sends the Query on each change event (https://pub.dev/documentation/objectbox/latest/objectbox/QueryBuilder/watch.html). So either the above or applying a limit in the map() call should work (e.limit = 10;)?

That is what i looked for! e.limit = 10 Thank you!
